# Using Queue() to share files in a distributed application with python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, distributed-computing, file-sharing

Master:

have multiple files that he need to apply the same function for each file, so i considered each file as a Job and I put them in a Queue().

Worker:

Each process get a job from the shared queue and process the file in it and return the processed file.

My question is :

Do I have to send the file from master to worker or just share it with the Queue() ?

for information : the file here is a video sequence.

Comment: "send it" versus "share it" .... what is the difference? Interprocess queues share things by sending them. Generally, one would send the file name to the worker and let it open it.

Comment: Are you using a distributed application framework for this?

Comment: No just the standard library multiprocessing, I followed this [link](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/01/24/distributed-computing-in-python-with-multiprocessing/)  for the implementation.

Comment: I just shared the queue containing all files name and I got an error from the worker saying that there is  No such file or directory.

Comment: In an other try, I shared an object_File with the queue instead of the file_name, but I also got an error from the worker saying : `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<uninitialized file>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do here, all very abstract really by the way, is to share the Queue(), and each worker ask if "has something to do, else they sleep (lock)

Comment: So even if the worker run on a different machine, he will get the file from the Queue() ?

Comment: @Sendja - does your Queue work on multiple machines?

Comment: I don't know , I don't have multiple machine to test it. Would it work with Virtual Machines?

Comment: Yes it should work, with a virtual machine you can try as well